# String lookup/matching between two columns

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

Let's consider two tables:

- A (word varchar2(200));
- B (syllable varchar2(5));

Now we want to create a table C which would be the mapping between words and syllables (of course 1 word corresponds to many syllables and 1 syllable corresponds to many words):
C (word, syllable)

Here is how we build this table:

```
Select word, syllable
From A
Join B
  On instr(word,syllable)>0;
```

But this is running slow, around 2 hours for 100k words and 150k syllables.

We tried several ways to improve this (hints, indexes...), but with no success.
We will soon try oracle text indexing but we don't have the specific rights yet.

Would anyone have an idea on what we could try to improve the performances? It's a major problem for us, since we are planning on increasing the size or data, it will become insanely long...

Answer (score 0):

This is doing a Cartesian join, so 100K * 150K = 15 billion rows, then applying the `INSTR` function to the result. About the only way to make this run better is to throw parallelism at it, assuming you have a database host with sufficient CPU. Ask your DBA if in doubt:

```
select /*+ parallel(16) */ word, syllable, etc....
```

I suppose you *could* make this faster by writing a PL/SQL script that takes each `word` and progressively takes the first character, then the first two characters, then the first three, etc.. then the second character, then the second and third, etc.. then the third, then the third and fourth, etc.. basically extracting every possible sequence of characters that could be a syllable, then doing an equality seek on an index sitting on the syllable table. That at least would avoid the Cartesian join.